# Breaking early when iterating table rows and cells

Tags: cypress

I have a table with 10 columns in each row, but I need to break the loop after performing operations with 2nd column in each row using cypress

```js
cy.get(tablerows).find('td').each((ele,index) => {
  HERE I NEED TO BREAK THE LOOP AFTER 2 COLUMNS FOR EACH ROW, PLEASE HELP ME.
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you break early using a single `.each()` you will only get the first row processed, because `cy.get(tablerows).find('td')` gives you one big stream of all the cells in all the rows.

Instead, use one `.each()` for rows and another for cells in the row

```js
cy.get(tablerows).each($row => {

  cy.wrap($row).find('td').each(($cell, index) => {

    if (index > 1) {
      return false
    } 

    // test first two columns here

  })
})
```

Or pre-filter the columns

```js
cy.get(tablerows).each($row => {

  cy.wrap($row).find('td')
    .then($tds => [...$tds].slice(0,2))
    .each(($cell, index) => {

      // only first two columns passed here

    })
})
```

Comment: I tried with first code snippet sir, it worked thank you soo much for your help .

Answer (score 0):

[You can exit `cy.each()` by returning `false`.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Return-early)

```js
cy.get(tablerows).find('td').each((ele, index) => {
  if (index > 1) {
    return false
  } else {
  // code to execute in first two iterations
  }
});
```

If you are only running synchronous code, you can omit the `else`.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for your answer. I have tried this already, here the the index Is referring to rows,  index >1 stopped my execution after 2nd row, not second column of first row. Anyways I will verify once again. Thank you

Comment: What are you using to select the column? You'll probably need to do the `return false` inside of the `.each()` that selects each column within the row.

Comment: I am using "ele" to get the data in the columns and then verifying the data, even now I tried with the above approach. It stopped execution after 2 columns in 1st row itself. 

Comment: Can you please post the HTML for the table in your OP?